# Convert arrays in one in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, ascii-art

I have dictionary:

```
dict = {"basic": {"last_name":["tomson", "brown"], "first_name":["paul", "max"]}}
```

And I would like to write function that convert it in this:

```
table = [["tomson", "paul"],
        ["brown", "max"]]
```

For `terminaltables` module:

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

table_data = [["last_name", "first_name"]]
table_data.append(table)

ascii_table = AsciiTable(table_data)
print "\n" + ascii_table.table + "\n"
```

With result:

```
+----------+-----------+
|last_name |first_name |
+----------+-----------+
|tomson    |paul       |
|brown     |max        |
+----------+-----------+
```

Please help me! I'm sorry for my English :)

Comment: `table = [value for (key, value) in dict["basic"].items()]`?

Comment: Yeah, it works! Great! Thank you!

Comment: oh, no , this is wrong. it's my mistake. sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also need to "rotate" the list:

```
table = [list(reversed(x)) for x in zip(*dict['basic'].values())]
```

Comment: OP this is what you want

Comment: @darker0n If the reversed didn't give you what you want then you should change what you want in the question, because when I run with reversed I get `[['tomson', 'paul'], ['brown', 'max']]`, which is what you said you wanted in the question. Without reversed I get `[['paul', 'tomson'], ['max', 'brown']]` which is different then what you said you wanted in your question

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question the final list you want is a zip of the two lists inside the dictionary.
To get the lists call [values()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and to zip call [zip([iterable, ...])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

For some reason the zip output is reversed, so to get the original order you wanted you have to run each list through [reversed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).

The final code would be:

```
[list(reversed(x)) for x in zip(*dict["basic"].values())]
```

PS: As Daniel Roseman said calling the dictionary "dict" will shadow the built-in. That means that if after assigning the dictionary to "dict" you want to use the built-in `dict` in any way (e.g. transforming a tuple into a dictionary) the built-in won't be available.

Comment: great answer, but i have this: ``[("tomson", "paul"), ("brown", "max")]``

Comment: If I run `zip(*dict.values())` I get `[('first_name',), ('last_name',)]`

Comment: @heinst +1, same thing

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the ["basic"]. Now it should give the output you desire.

Comment: Indeed, for some reason zip reverses the output. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 4):

No need for the comprehension:

```
dict["basic"].values()
```

Also note it's a bad idea to call your variable `dict`, as it shadows the built-in dict function.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong and this answer is wrong because the values are not "rotated" as @valtuarte said.

Comment: This doesn't give the OP the output he wants